# wait for N-1 out of N threads to end, then issue an instruction for the last thread

Tags: java, multithreading

So, i apologize for the title. It's quite hard to explain in one sentence what i would like to do if you have no idea on how it is called.

So assume i can only use primitive thread functions (wait, notify, no concurrent package)

The program has 3 threads, all of them are the same and are called by the main thread. They behave normally until one of the three get an exception and so it must wait for the end of the remaining 2 threads in order to start a recovery process.
I was thinking about a static variable but I'm not really sure about it, i would love to keep it as simple as possible.

Each thread starts at the same time.

Comment: You need mutex. In that way it can be used as some kind of counter to know which thread is finishing/starting by doing count up/down

Comment: `synchronized` block would be helpful. As long as to check whether 2nd thread completed its work you can use the `thread.isAlive()` method.

Comment: Why are you making life difficult for yourself by stipulating "no concurrent package"?  It sounds to me like a CyclicBarrier would solve this rather elegantly.

Comment: @hagubear do you mean like semaphores?

Comment: @VighaneshGursale how can i check if other threads are alive?

Comment: the concept is semaphores - yes. May be it's an overkill for what you're trying to do, but it's the first thing that came in my mind.

Comment: @user217354 if you are creating thread using object. You can use `obj.thread.isAlive()`

Comment: @IanRoberts im not working on a standard java library

Comment: in which case, please tag the question appropriately (java-me or whatever it is you're using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you can't use a static variable like you suggest. Here's how I would do it with an inner class...

```
private static boolean running = true;

public void test26546397() {

    while (true) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        running = true;
        // Do recovery
    }
}


public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                // doStuff
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would of course replace the `while (true)` with something a little more suitable.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to mark the `boolean` as `volatile` otherwise you are not guaranteed that the value is going to be seen by other threads

Answer (score 1):

I think you need java.concurrent.CountdownLatch, however if the java.concurrent package is not available to you can code this yourself using Object.wait/notify and synchronized blocks.

The latch can then be decremented in a finally {} on each Thread, this will be run if the Thread completes, or an exception occurs.

Your main program then just needs to wait for count to become 0.

```
public class StackOverflow26546397 {

    static class CountdownLatch {
        private int count;
        private Object monitor = new Object();

        public CountdownLatch(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public void countDown() {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                count--;
                monitor.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        public void await() throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                while (count > 0) {
                    monitor.wait();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class Job implements Runnable {
        private CountdownLatch latch;

        public Job(CountdownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do work.
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 3000d));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //
            } finally {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(3);

        new Thread(new Job(latch)).start();
        new Thread(new Job(latch)).start();
        new Thread(new Job(latch)).start();

        latch.await();
        System.out.println("All threads finished");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but this is as simple as I can think of (just native concurrency):
Create a static or shared `volatile` boolean

`private static volatile boolean exceptionOccured=false`

Set the above to 'true' when exception occurs:

`....}catch(Exception e){
   exceptionOccured=true;
}`

Check this periodically in you normal thread flow:

`if (exceptionOccured)
  //enter you synchronized call here`

the synchronized method could look something like:

`public synchronized void checkAndRecover(){
   //decrement a counter or other logic to identify which is the last Thread and then 
   //perform any recovery logic
}`